# Normalizing each column in R

Tags: r

Normalize each column.

the data starts off with the first row having x and y then continues with numbers and i believe that is the problem.

```
> normalize <- function(number) {
+ return ((number - min(number)) / (max(number) - min(number)))
+ }
> data$V1_norm<-normalize(data$V1)
> data$V2_norm<-normalize(data$V2)


> data$V1_norm<-normalize(data$V1)
Error in Summary.factor(c(69L, 1L, 22L, 9L, 29L, 44L, 65L, 21L, 61L, 4L,  : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors

> data$V2_norm<-normalize(data$V2)
Error in Summary.factor(c(53L, 27L, 46L, 36L, 33L, 41L, 8L, 15L, 12L,  : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: You have unordered `factor` variables, so you can't take a min or max. You need to convert to a numeric or integer first. At the moment it is like literally deciding which is less, "cat" or "apple"?

Comment: Having a string like `"x"` in the first row of a column of numbers is often a sign that you should have read the data in with a setting like `header = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine. I believe your problem is in the *V1_norm* and *V2_norm* in the *data* object. Both variables are factors.

```
normalize <- function(number) { 
    return ((number - min(number)) / (max(number) - min(number)))}

data$V1_norm <- normalize(data$V1) 
data$V2_norm <- normalize(data$V2)

data <- data.frame(V1_norm = c(6,1,10,2), V2_norm = c(10,20,100,40))

normalize(data$V1) # returns 0.5555556 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.1111111
normalize(data$V2) # returns 0.0000000 0.1111111 1.0000000 0.3333333
```

Try this in your dataset:

```
class(data$V1) 
class(data$V2)
```

Be careful with functions such as **as.numeric()**,you should double check where is the inconsistency in your data.